# Google Analytics API Connect multiple website

Tags: analytics

I want to create a SEO tool where every website owner can view their traffic and and much more things, just like google analytics. How can i do this using google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you’re looking at using the Google Analytics API to build your own reporting tool?